# How to receive the production receipt with SKReceiptRefreshRequest when debugging?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

When trying to download the receipt while debugging the app with Xcode, I always receive the sandbox receipt instead of the production receipt:

```
receiptRequest = SKReceiptRefreshRequest(receiptProperties: nil)
receiptRequest?.delegate = self
receiptRequest?.start()
```

Also `Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL` returns `.../sandboxReceipt`, so the restore requests seem to be towards the App Store sandbox environment.

The logged in Apple ID on the device is a normal Apple ID that has an active subscription for the product. I want to download that specific receipt from the production environment.

How can I receive that receipt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That actually seem to be not possible, according to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2259/_index.html):

> StoreKit connects to the sandbox environment when you launch your application from Xcode, from your test device (iOS and tvOS), or from the Finder (macOS). It connects to a production environment for applications that were downloaded from the App Store.

Quite inconvenient.

Comment: I just don't understand how we are supposed to test when certain fields on the receipt are always wrong in the sandbox. Makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: that's it, very sad to hear... need to test over prod so much but seems not to be possible